# Training a MLP after pretraining RBMs with dropout

Tags: restricted-boltzmann-machine, backpropagation, dropout

Let's say I have a couple of RBMs that I pretrained and that I used dropout. When finetuning, how does having used dropout effect backpropagation? Do I still use dropout while backprogating and change only a couple of weights each iteration?